# How to highlight a clicked row in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried the other solutions but none of them have worked for me. They usually involve using the 'id' attribute of the rows in ng-repeat rows. But my table looks something like this.`

```
<table>
    <tr class="serviceRows" ng-repeat="(key, value) in serviceNameAndStatus | custom:search track by $index">
        <td> {{key}} </td>
        <td> {{value.status}} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am not able to use the id property. I need an alternative way to highlight the clicked row in the table.

Comment: you can use put $index value to someVariable after click, and set prober class to `td` if someVariable==$index

Comment: so `onclick="this.classList.toggle('selected')"`

Comment: use ng-click and ng-class

Comment: You can try this: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/F8Y7kANH5OXwfyXCSk2f?p=preview)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks a lot ! Worked like a charm.